# What does the "^" do in python

Tags: python

I'm struggling to find documentation on what the ^ does in python.

EX.

> > > 6^1 =
> > >       7
> > >
> > > 6^2 =
> > >       4
> > >
> > > 6^3 =
> > >       5
> > >
> > > 6^4 =
> > >       2
> > >
> > > 6^5 =
> > >       3
> > >
> > > 6^6 =
> > >       0

Help?

Comment: I'm not a Python progammer, but this is pretty obviously a bitwise XOR.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's only obvious if you've seen a bitwise XOR before.

Comment: @PhilipKendall it wasn't obvious to me at all, despite that i am a c/c++/java programmer learning python.

Comment: @randomstring: .. but it's the same in c,c++, and java.  Admittedly it's possible to avoid using it much.  BTW, for help on Python syntax you can type `help("^")` etc. at the console.

Comment: @DSM yes, it was just the context it was presented in prevented me from making the connection. i felt silly when i did realize what it was. i was thinking it was some special functional programming thingamagic and i laughed when i realized it was xor. thanks for the help on python help

Answer (score 8):

It is the [bitwise exclusive-or operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor#Bitwise_operation), often called "xor". For each pair of corresponding bits in the operands, the corresponding bit in the result is 0 if the operand bits are the same, 1 if they are different.

Consider `6^4`:

```
  6 = 0b0110
  4 = 0b0100
6^4 = 0b0010 = 2
```

As you can see the least-significant bit (the one on the right, in the "one's" place) is zero in both numbers. Thus the least-significant bit in the answer is zero. The next bit is `1` in the first operand and `0` in the second, so the result is `1`.

XOR has some interesting properties:

```
a^b == b^a  # xor is commutative
a^(b^c) == (a^b)^c   # xor is associative
(a^b)^b == a  # xor is reversible
0^a == a   # 0 is the identity value
a^a == 0   # xor yourself and you go away.
```

You can change the oddness of a value with xor:

```
prev_even = odd ^ 1 (2 = 3 ^ 1)
next_odd = even ^ 1 (3 = 2 ^ 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

for more information on XOR , please react the documentation on Python.org at here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: That's not very helpful